# Is there a way to combine several where clauses with inside if-statements in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, where-clause

I'm new here and new to rails. I'm currently trying to make an own search function for the database (books) of my training project. I don't want to implement an existing search form because I just want to learn.
So far it is working but now I added a dropdown menu to choose a comparison symbol from. Based on that it shall find the books with a rating ("==", ">=" or "<=").

I tried setting the if clauses before the whole where-part but that means I would need to have the whole where-part three times. I was hoping there is a shorter way to achieve that?
Thank you in advance!

```ruby
def self.advanced_search(s_name, s_author, s_comp_sign, s_rating)  

  where("lower(name) LIKE ?", "%#{s_name}%").  
  where("lower(author) LIKE ?", "%#{s_author}%").  
  where(:rating == s_rating) #if s_comp_sign == "="
  where(:rating >= s_rating) #if s_comp_sign == ">"
  where(:rating <= s_rating) #if s_comp_sign == "<"

end
```

Comment: `q = M.where(a).where(b)` is equivalent to `q = M.where(a); q = q.where(b)`.

Answer (score 1):

As you need to do where query on the same field according to the operator the user chooses you may do it like this:

**Method 1:**

Add a method which will return the correct operator based on what you receive from the view:

```
def operator_chosen(op)
  case op
  when '>'
    '>='
  when '<'
    '<='
  when '='
    '=='
  else
    '<>'
  end
end
```

I have added not equals to as the default case you may use equals to as the default one. And then you can do like this:

```
where("rating #{operator_chosen(s_comp_sign)} s_rating") if s_comp_sign.present?
```

**Method 2:**

You can do it using ternary operator too, but the code will not be that readable, it will look complex, like this:

```
op = (s_comp_sign == '>' ? '>=' : (s_comp_sign == '<' ? '<=' : '=='))
```

Here the default will be `==` and then this can be used as:

```
where("rating #{op} s_rating") if s_comp_sign.present?
```

Answer (score -1):

One of the ways to avoid this would be creating a storing a condition in a string before querying the data.

For example:
    
    `rating_condition = "rating " + s_comp_sign + " ?"`

and then querying like this: 
    
    `where("lower(name) LIKE ?", "%#{s_name}%").

    where("lower(author) LIKE ?", "%#{s_author}%").

    where(rating_condition,s_rating)`

Comment: How about string interpolation instead of addition? Also, it looks like you might need a `=` in that interpolated string...